# Error installing python package with pip (TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION)

Tags: python, openssl, pip, python-3.6, sles

I'm on Suse Linux Enterprise 11 SP4 and I'm trying to install a python package using pip but it's failing with the following error:

Env:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.6

$ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /home/<<user>>/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Command:

```
$ pip install sendgrid
```

Error:

```
Collecting sendgrid
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:841)'),)': /simple/sendgrid/
...
...
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/sendgrid/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/sendgrid/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:841)'),)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sendgrid (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sendgrid
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:841)'),)) - skipping
```

I have tried [all this solutions](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4205) but none of them had work on SLES.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your internet working properly ?

Comment: Yes sure!, It's an EC2 instance and I tested connection with `curl -I https://pypi.org/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get it to work!

Seems that the openssl library that came installed by default on SLES 11 SP4 (`libopenssl-devel`) is really outdated (`OpenSSL 0.9.8`)

To verify this you can run:

```
$ python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 0.9.8j-fips 07 Jan 2009
```

The trick is to **uninstall** `libopenssl-devel` and **install** `libopenssl1-devel` like this:

**IMPORTANT:** Note that you will be asked to take an option, please select **deinstallation of libopenssl-devel-0.9.x-x.xxx.x.x.x**

```
$ sudo zypper install libopenssl1-devel

Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: libopenssl1-devel-1.0.1g-0.58.9.1.x86_64 conflicts with libopenssl-devel < 1.0.1 provided by libopenssl-devel-0.9.8j-0.106.9.1.x86_64
 Solution 1: deinstallation of libopenssl-devel-0.9.8j-0.106.9.1.x86_64
 Solution 2: do not install libopenssl1-devel-1.0.1g-0.58.9.1.x86_64

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c): 1
Resolving dependencies...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following NEW package is going to be installed:
  libopenssl1-devel 

The following package is going to be REMOVED:
  libopenssl-devel 

1 new package to install, 1 to remove.
Overall download size: 3.3 MiB. After the operation, 698.0 KiB will be freed.
Continue? [y/n/? shows all options] (y): 
Retrieving package libopenssl1-devel-1.0.1g-0.58.9.1.x86_64 (1/1), 3.3 MiB (19.6 MiB unpacked)
Retrieving: libopenssl1-devel-1.0.1g-0.58.9.1.x86_64.rpm [done]
Removing libopenssl-devel-0.9.8j-0.106.9.1 [done]
Installing: libopenssl1-devel-1.0.1g-0.58.9.1 [done]
```

Now procede to recompile/reinstall your python env with:

```
$ CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/openssl1 LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64 pyenv install 3.6.6
```

Finally verify that your `OpenSSL` version is the new one and proceed to install your package with `pip`:

```
$ python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014

$ pip install sendgrid
```

Hope it helps you!

Please see ['Security Module in SUSE Linux Enterprise 11'](https://www.suse.com/documentation/suse-best-practices/singlehtml/securitymodule/securitymodule.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore SSL errors by setting pypi.org and files.pythonhosted.org as trusted hosts.

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name>
```

Or:

Try installing using the wheel of the package

Comment: Hi, Agile, thanks for your answer but it doesn't work, I had already tried that before asking here (It's one of the proposals on the github link I posted above) https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4205#issuecomment-277299106

Comment: No it doesn't... the issue seems related to an outdated version of openssl library https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/829, I'm working on see if updating it will solve the issue...